# Python pickle to xml

Tags: python, xml, pickle

How can I convert to a pickle object to a xml document?

For example, I have a pickle like that:

```
cpyplusplus_test
Coordinate
p0
(I23
I-11
tp1
Rp2
.
```

I want to get something like:

```
<Coordinate>
  <x>23</x>
  <y>-11</y>
</Coordinate>
```

The Coordinate class has x and y attributes of course. I can supply a xml schema for conversion.

I tried gnosis.xml module. It can objectify xml documents to python object. But it cannot serialize objects to xml documents like above.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the code that created this pickle?

Comment: @alecxe The code is here:  

`cord = pyplusplus_test.Coordinate(10,10)
cord.x = 23
cord.y = -11 
tmpStr = pickle.dumps(cord)
print tmpStr`

Answer (score 4):

`gnosis.xml` does support pickling to XML:

```
import gnosis.xml.pickle
xml_str = gnosis.xml.pickle.dumps(obj)
```

To deserialize the XML, use `loads`:

```
o2 = gnosis.xml.pickle.loads(xml_str)
```

Of course, this will not directly convert existing pickles to XML — you have to first deserialize them into live object, and then dump them to XML.

Having said that, I must warn you that `gnosis.xml` is quite slow, somewhat fragile, and most likely unmaintained (last release was over six years ago). It is also very bloated, containing a huge number of subpackages with lots and lots of features that not only you won't need, but are untested and buggy. We tried to use for our development and, after a lot of effort wasted on trying to debug and improve it, ended up writing a simple XML pickler running at ~500 lines of code, and never looked back.

Comment: You are right, gnosis supports pickling to XML. But there are two concerns. First, its XML schema isn't class oriented. For instance a string member serialized as `<attr name="s" type="string" value="abc" />` However, I want to `<s>abc<</s>` format. Second, I use types from C++ libraries via boost.python. gnosis pickles them in raw pickle format. For my Coordinate class: `<attr name="__toplevel__" family="atom" type="rawpickle" >»»cpyplusplus_test
Coordinate
p1
(I23
I-11
tRp2
.««</attr>`

Comment: @QQ If your XML syntax is fixed, then obviously gnosis.xml will not be of much use, and I'm fairly certain you'll have to write your own serializer. As for the "rawpickle" thing, it's likely a result of gnosis.xml not knowing how to serialize the class, and leaving it up to pickle to do it. To fix that, you will need to write a gnosis.xml "extension" (there is some documentation on how to do that), but that will still not come close to fixing your first problem. Finally, the warnings about gnosis.xml from the final paragraph of my answer still apply.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342 My main goal was to find a common data exchange format between python and other languages. (c++, c#, etc). I generated class declarations from the same model for various languages. But it seems impossible to share objects in xml format between a python script and a program written in a different language.

Comment: @QQ You didn't mention that in the question, but now you did, things are becoming clearer. Does it have to be XML? json works fine in Python and is not exactly unknown in other languages.

Comment: I have just tried to clearify the problem. I tested json a little. There are some implementation problems. But I suppose that asking another question may be better. Thanks @user4815162342

Comment: For future readers - Gnosis doesn't work with Python 3, using string.join which was removed.

Comment: @user4815162342 You should have shared that xml pickler in order not to have to rewrite again.

Comment: @GyulaSámuelKarli Sadly I was (and still am) not allowed to share it, as the code is owned by the company I worked for at the time. I tried to open source it, which was approved in principle, but got stuck because it requires some effort to extract the serializer from the rest of the project, with too little business interest to justify the investment.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to unpickle the data by `pickle.load` or `pickle.loads`. Then generate xml snippet. If you have a pickle in `tmpStr` variable, simply do this:

```
c = pickle.loads(tmpStr)
print '<Coordinate>\n<x>%d</x>\n<y>%d</y>\n</Coordinate>' % (c.x, c.y)
```

Writing to file is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I don't want to embed xml code to the script. I want to serialize object automatically with a method call similar to `serializationManager.serialize(c, 'c.xml')`