# How to save the QTreeItem structure created by user in xml file?

Tags: python, xml, pyside, elementtree, qtreewidgetitem

How to create xml file contains the level hierarchy structure of the QTreeWidgetItem which is created by user,I'm using (ETreeElement for creating xml file)?, I tried to do this by making the xml file get the structure during the user create it but i only got the root item with the first Child i can't get the other items

```
def rootItem(self):
    itemName = self.TreeviewForFolders.topLevelItem(0).text(0)
    return itemName


def addItem(self, name, parent):
    self.TreeviewForFolders.expandItem(parent)
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
    item.setText(0,name)
    item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    return item

def addFolders(self):
    item = self.TreeviewForFolders.invisibleRootItem()

    if(self.TreeviewForFolders.topLevelItemCount() == 0):
        self.addItem("Item", item)
        root = Element(str(self.rootItem()))

    else:
        if(len(self.TreeviewForFolders.selectedItems()) > 0):
            item = self.TreeviewForFolders.selectedItems()[0]
            self.addItem("Item", item)

            root = Element(str(self.rootItem()))
            child = SubElement(root, "Item")



    output_file = open( 'Tamplet.xml', 'w' )
    output_file.write( '<?xml version="1.0"?>' )
    output_file.write( ElementTree.tostring( root ) )
    output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly just write an object to file ,you have to serialize it.

Use this gnosisxml library to serialize a object to xml: [From here](http://freecode.com/projects/gnosisxml/)

For details view this  [stackoverflow  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851774/python-pickle-to-xml)